# Playing mandolin just strumming

Tags: theory, chords, practice, strumming, mandolin

I don't understand how to play chords on mandolin, the most of the tabs avaiable are with mandolin chords but I know it is possible to play a song just strumming, and I find that way so much easier... Can someone explain this to me? How can I know how the correct notes for a certain song, just strumming?
here is an example of what i'm trying to explain

Answer (score 2):

What you're featuring here are *two* mandolins playing. The one shown is playing a single note tune, while the other is playing chords - strumming.

So, your question is confusing as it stands. Chords are generally *strummed* - and really one wouldn't call playing the two strings at a time, producing a melody, (as in the video) strumming.

Could you please, with this info. available, explain more clearly exactly what you need - chords or melody. Both of which are available on mandolin music. By the way, strumming the chords alone will not make the melody stand out - it's mainly as an accompaniment.